# Как передать в функцию массив значений сформированный в другой функции?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пытаюсь реализовать посекционный скролл на react. Получил позицию каждой секции на странице с помощью `window.onload()`:

```
export default function Home() {
let yPositions = []
    window.onload = () => {
        Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('section')).map((sectionItem, index) => {
            yPositions.push(sectionItem.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.documentElement.scrollTop)
            return yPositions
        })
    }
```

Хочу передать сформированный массив в handleScroll:

```
const handleScroll = (yPositions) => {
        let i = 0
        let currentScrollPosition = window.scrollY + yPositions[i]
        setScroll(yPositions[i]);
        let windowScrolls = window.scrollY;
        i++;
        console.log(yPositions)
        if (windowScrolls > 0) toTopBtnRef.current.classList.add("totopbtn--active")
        else toTopBtnRef.current.classList.remove("totopbtn--active")
    };
return (...код компонента)
}
```

Но туда передается пустой массив. Как его правильно передать? Вызываю handleScroll так:

```
    const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll(yPositions));

        return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);


    }, []);
```

Comment: @user7860670 Добавил мой useEffect.

Comment: В вашем useEffect переменная yPositions равна начальному значению при установке компонента. Так же при создании евента вы вызываете функцию, а не передаете ее в качестве обработчика

Comment: @SwaD Как передать туда не начальное значение? yPositions нужно передавать в массив зависимостей?

Comment: @SwaD yPositions = window.onload() ?

Comment: Где переменная yPositions размещена относительно компонента с функцией handleScroll?

Comment: @SwaD Внутри компонента

Comment: @SwaD Есть страница Home в ней до return объявлен useEffect и yPositions и window.onload переопределяется, потом return код компонента. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно не на загрузку страницы завязываться а на маунт компонента. Т.е. При маунте создавать массив и записывать его в стейт, а затем испрользовать этот массив при скроле